# Sending parameters with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to send some variables using ajax to a php page and then displaying them in a div but it isn't working.

Html code :

```
<div id="center">
    <form>                                  
        <input type="text" id="toSearch" class="inputText" title="Search for ...">              
        <select name="thelist1" id="ecoElem" class="comboBox">
            <option>-- Ecosystem Element --</option>
        </select> 
        <select name="thelist2" id="ecoActor" class="comboBox">                         
            <option>-- Ecosystem Actor --</option>
        </select>   
        <input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton" onclick="loadData();">
    </form>        
</div>
 <div id="resBox">
    </div>
```

The loadData function :

```
function loadData(){
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }

            searchT = document.getElementById('toSearch').value;
            ecoElem = document.getElementById('ecoElem').value;
            ecoActor = document.getElementById('ecoActor').value;

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById('resBox').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","databaseRead.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("text=" + searchT + "&elem=" + ecoElem + "&actor=" + ecoActor);}
```

and finally the php page :

```
<?php   
$searchT = $_POST['text'];
$ecoElem = $_POST['elem'];
$ecoActor = $_POST['actor'];
echo $searchT;
?>
```

That's it , I've been working on this for a few hours but still can't figure it out.

Comment: the div = resBox is a little below , forgot to put it in there

Comment: Is the page refreshing after you hit the submit button?
From the code I'm seeing the form is submitted regularly and the ajax callback most likely won't have a chance to run.

Comment: Actually when I set no parameters in the send() it is refreshing , but like this it is not.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when ajusting the code to put it in here and deleting all the comments and stuff , it did work well. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button so that the onclick return false (in case that is submitting the form)...

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton" onclick="loadData();return false;">
```

Also, you might want to URL encode the values from the textbox, otherwise somebody entering a = or a & will mess it all up...

```
xmlhttp.send("text=" + encodeURIComponent(searchT) + "&elem=" + + encodeURIComponent(ecoElem) + "&actor=" + + encodeURIComponent(ecoActor));}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JQuery.

```
function loadData(){   
     var searchT = $('#toSearch').val(); 
     var toSearch = $('#ecoActor ').val();    
     var ecoActor = $('#ecoActor').val();
     $.post("databaseRead.php"),{ text:searchT, elem:toSearch, actor:ecoActor },
          function(data){
          $('#resBox').html(data);
     });
}
```